# Oracle Table does not exist. ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

When I using this statement in Oracle to view the values of a table_name, I got this:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER
```

and I got this result

```
Table does not exist. ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This means the table values can not be display with SELECT statement?

Comment: Usually there is no schema named `user_tables` in Oracle. Did you create such a user/schema? If yes, then show us the `create table` statement for the table `table_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following statement to retrieve the owner of the object:

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from ALL_OBJECTS where object_name = 'MEMBER';
```

Referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947140/how-can-i-find-the-owner-of-an-object-in-oracle)

Then depending on the result(s) returned you would adjust your statement to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  <owner>.MEMBER;
```

...and replace `<owner>` with the owner that was returned in the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you select a specific column. Use this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
```

Comment: Yes I can list all table_name, but I can not list data value in any table with statement select * from

Comment: I have edited my question a little bit for easy understand.